# How to check that a sample suits multi-dimensional uniform distribution?

Tags: distributions, hypothesis-testing, estimation

I have a 3-dimensional sample $(X_k,Y_k,Z_k), k=1, \ldots, N$ which I suspect to be uniform on some parallelepiped in $R^3$ (i.e. a set of the form [a;b]X[c;d]X[e;f], where numbers a,b,c,d,e,f are unknown).

1. How should I estimate numbers a, b, c, d, e, f? Obviously I can try MLE, but then my estimates are biased. Does unbiased estimates exist?
2. How can I check that my sample is indeed uniform?

Answer (score 2):

1. For the 1D continuous uniform distribution U(a,b) the uniformly minimum variance unbiased (UMVU) estimates of a and b can be obtained in closed form by a [straightforward example of maximum spacing estimation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_spacing_estimation#Example_2) Can't see any reason that applying this separately for each dimension wouldn't give you UMVU estimates of all parameters of your multivariate uniform distribution

Comment: +1 Note that the MSE comes with a built-in goodness of fit estimate, so it solves problems #1 and #2 simultaneously.

Comment: @whuber (+1) Thanks, I hadn't noticed that. I admit I've never actually *used* maximum spacing estimation; I'd *heard* of it in connection with estimation for a uniform distribution and just checked Wikipedia.

Comment: Whuber and onestop thanks for the answers. Now I understand how to check that my marginal distributions X, Y and Z are uniform. However to prove that the joint distribution of (X,Y,Z) is uniform in R^3 we have to prove, that (X,Y,Z) are independent. So the question is: by given sample (X_k, Y_k, Z_k) how can I check whether random variables (X,Y,Z) are independent? Thanks!

Comment: Good question (i.e. i can't immediately think of an answer).

Comment: And is it possible to check whether say (X_k) and (Y_k) are independent?